# EACCES (Permission Denied) on Android 12

Tags: android

I am really having a hard time making my app work for Android 12.

I have these lines in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

<application
...
android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true"
... >

<activity
        android:name=".Home"
        android:exported="true"
        android:screenOrientation="sensorPortrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

</application>
```

I also have this snippet in Home.java:

```
if(Settings.Global.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.Global.AUTO_TIME, 0) == 1) {
            int permission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);

            if (permission != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                // We dont have permission so prompt the user
                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        this,
                        PERMISSIONS_STORAGE,
                        REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
                );

                ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, EXTERNAL_STORAGE_PERMISSION_CODE);

                tvStatus.setText("Please click \"allow\" for the app to work seamlessly. Then, click on the play button below");
                fbtnEnter.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                onClick(this, fbtnEnter, "restart");

                if(ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                        Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)
                        != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                    if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(this,
                            Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS)) {
                    }
                }
            }
```

This is the method I use to download the file:

```
static String[] getUsesAndUpdateData(String filename) throws IOException {
    FileInputStream fin = null;
    int ch;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
    String text = "";
    String[] fragments = new String[0];
    String accepted_characters = "0123456789ABCDEF,;";
    boolean check = true;
    try{
        fin = new FileInputStream(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS) + "/" + filename);
        while((ch = fin.read()) != -1) {
            check = accepted_characters.contains("" + (char) ch);
            if (check) {
                sb.append((char) ch);
            } else sb.append((char) 88);
        }
        text = sb.toString();
        fragments = text.split(";");
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        log("File not found" + e);
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
        log("Exception while reading file " + ioe);
    }
    finally {
        // close the stream using close method
        try {
            if (fin != null) fin.close();
        }
        catch (IOException ioe) {
            log("Error while closing stream: " + ioe);
        }
    }
    return fragments;
}
```

Checking the logcat, I can see the ff:

```
2022-10-04 18:51:02.593 11754-11754/com.samp.test I/MVPX: File not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text1.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2022-10-04 18:51:02.602 11754-11754/com.samp.test I/MVPX: File not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text2.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2022-10-04 18:51:02.614 11754-11754/com.samp.test I/MVPX: File not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text1.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2022-10-04 18:51:02.629 11754-11754/com.samp.test I/MVPX: File not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text2.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2022-10-04 18:51:02.656 11754-11754/com.samp.test I/MVPX: File not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text1.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2022-10-04 18:51:02.669 11754-11754/com.samp.test I/MVPX: File not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text2.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2022-10-04 18:51:02.696 11754-11754/com.samp.test I/MVPX: File not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text1.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2022-10-04 18:51:02.712 11754-11754/com.samp.test I/MVPX: File not foundjava.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Documents/text2.txt: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
```

I tried several options and workarounds, but when I run the app in Android 12, I always get an EACCES permission error. I run out of things to try to make it work. Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: You need to **read and understand** all of [this article](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). Storage permissions have changed significantly and there's no single, simple, universally applicable replacement to the overly broad permissions that were granted in earlier version. The correct fix likely requires some serious re-design work on your part to get correct.

Comment: "I always get an EACCES permission error" -- there is no file I/O in your question. I recommend that you edit your question and provide a [mcve] that shows the full stack trace of your error, along with the code that triggers that error.

Comment: @CommonsWare I don't know if they are enough, but I already updated my question. Kindly check. Thank you.

Comment: None of your `log()` lines are logging the stack trace, which would be a good idea. In general, `Documents/` has limitations on Android 11+, so I recommend that you start by writing your content elsewhere, such as `getFilesDir()` or `getExternalFilesDir()` on `Context`.

Comment: Every app can create files in public Documents directory also on Android 11+ devices. Just the normal WRITE permission is enough.